# This tall than me

Tags: word-usage

I've read this sentence online. Does it sound fine?

> I've never been with someone **this tall than me** before.

Is the use of "this" natural here?

Answer (score 1):

No.

*I've never been with someone this tall than me before* is not grammatical. The segment *this tall than me* makes no sense. I think you mean *this much taller than me*, as in:

> I've never been with someone **this much taller than me** before.